# Need recommendations for a function with certain properties

Tags: functions, economics

Not sure if this might be a strange way of posing a question, but anyway:

I need a function $f(v,p,a)$ with the following properties:

- it is defined for $v \in [-\infty,\infty]$
- it is defined for $p \in [0,1]$
- $f$ equals 0 at $p=0$ and $v$ at $p=1$
- it is either concave or convex (in $f$) depending on the value of $a$, and a straight line for one value of $a$.  not sure if $a$ is defined on the real line or strictly positive

the exact form doesn't matter so long as it fits those characteristics -- the parameter $a$ is imaginary inasmuch as it depends on the functional form.

for context, I am dabbling in economics and trying to find a way to reconcile Klibanoff's smooth ambiguity model with mean-sd utility, given objective probability measures for the probability of a mean model and a conditional heteroskedasticity model.

Comment: I guess.  In words:  "between and including these numbers"

Comment: though I guess that it would never be infinity.  remind me the difference between a brace and a bracket?

Comment: why not writing $v \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: concave or convex in which variable? $v$, $p$ or $(v,p)$ together?

Comment: @hello: you should edit your question to make it clear that you want concavity/convexity on $p$. Also the second part of you comment is puzzling: $v$ does not depend on $p$ so how could $v$ get bigger as $p$ gets bigger? Did you mean that $f$ should get bigger as $p$ gets bigger? You would probably get better answers if you gave a little more thought to your question to make sure that it includes every property you want your function to satisfy.

Comment: sorry, edited.  and I meant that f should get bigger, not v.

Comment: @hello: your edit is not accurate yet. You wrote concave/convex in $f$ which does not make sense : concavity and convexity must be with respect to some variable(s). Also, if as you wrote in your previous comment, it matters to you that the function be increasing in $p$, you should really mention it.

Answer (score 2):

If I read you right (assuming you mean concavity/convexity in $v$), I think this should do the job

> $f : \mathbb{R} \times [0,1] \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}_{++} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(v,p,a,c) = (1-p)p(1-a)[c^v] + pv$

$c$ is an additional positive parameter you can chose the value of.

You can check that, as required

- $f$ is defined for any real value of $v$
- $p=0$ implies $f=0$ and $p=1$ implies $f = v$
- The convexity/concavity in $v$ of the function depend on the value of $a$ with the function being a straight line for $a = 1$.

I encoded the function on desmos at https://www.desmos.com/calculator/v8gniwvz6e. There you can play with the parameters and see how the shape of the function changes.